# Flutter: Unimplemented handling of missing static target

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I am running my first Flutter project
2. I created a sample project and I was able to run the app in
   simulator

I have edited the file `main.dart`

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Text('Hello World')));
```

**Now I am getting the error :**

[image]

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: I think you have to put your text in stateful or stateless class

Comment: @JoshuaCraven .... I have added the `pubspec.yaml` code

Comment: @HardikKumbhani ... How to do that ! ... I am new to flutter and this is the first file i am working

Comment: where is your boiler plate code whenever we created new project?

Comment: Copy this code and try again to run your project

Comment: https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/Devrath.dart please use this code

Comment: I had the same problem in another situation. What I did was simply switch to StatefulWidget and a HotRestart =)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your code works for me...

Have you tried a hot restart? The shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+\ or just click the button with the green circle-arrow in the console-window

I'm not sure what that error is, since I can't replicate it. However, this is more like what your app should look like. Give this a shot and see if it works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Hello World'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do we need to use the `StatelessWidget` compulsorily  ?

Comment: Ya man build method is compulsory for rendering your ui screen and you can found build method inside stateless or stateful widget

Comment: I had the same problem and your code also worked for me.

Comment: You don't need StatelessWidget, but you do need something that can invoke MediaQuery.of

That can be easily implemented by implementing `MaterialApp()` at the top of your widget tree.

Comment: This answer is better for beginners: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557571/9636037

Comment: It happens when you completely update the app class (in your case "MyApp"). So the hot reload doesn't work and you need to rebuild and rerun the project.

Comment: Can the `home:` really be just a `Text()` widget...? Shouldn't it be a screen, with a `Scaffold()` and stuff in it...?

Answer (score 399):

The same error occurred for me at first ... but it worked when I did a 'hot restart'

Comment: Worked for me, too. For everyone like me, who's not that familiar: The shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+\ or just click the button with the green circle-arrow in the console-window - it will re-sync files to the device.

Comment: Worked for me too. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: flutter tip: when there is an error, assume there is none, first restart

Comment: just stop the run app and start again

Comment: Thanks! Just had an heart attack because of this haha

Comment: thanks, as simple as hot restart solved the problem :)

Answer (score 95):

Just compile the project again and it will work. The error occurs because static variables are hard compiled on the executable and are not dynamic. If you hot reload the changes, it will not rebuild the executable (apk), so that's why you need to rebuild the app.

Answer (score 36):

Just delete the build and recompile. It worked for me. Use the following code:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: am sorry but isnt this killing a mosquito with AK-47?

Seems like a very long way to go for a restart

Comment: Sometimes hot reload wont fix the problem.

Comment: Ahaa, but a person should start with reloading first..

Answer (score 23):

Usually, a Full App Restart is required after a heavy logic change, as transforming a StatelessWidget into StatefulWidget.  [Check André Glatzl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530278/3900793)

In **Android Studio** use the Flutter Hot Restart

[image: Flutter Hot Restart]

Answer (score 9):

A hot restart will work. But the source of the problem might be as follows.

You've created new project. You've deleted boilerplate code and try to modify without a stateful or stateless widget. Flutter tries to rebuild widgets under build() method. But when you hot reload, flutter might not resolve what you've updated.

Another example of such error is, when we create a new static variable(static String token = "abc";) in one Class (like constants.dart) and try to reference them in another screen (constants.token), flutter failed to resolve such static things when we hotreload. but it work fine when we hotrestart.

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons this happens is you are running the app for the first time and then you make some changes and reload again. Without reloading, stop the execution, and again run the app from scratch, this error won't come.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same situation, I fixed it by running the app again, This issue is caused when you applied a lot of change to your code and pressed the hot reload button.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the app worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command again

```
'flutter run'
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

You changed the myApp and created your own MaterialApp so all you have to do is after changing the name into MaterialApp instead of hot restart click the play button. It will work.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just press the red stop button and click the play button again. It will work :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have added a Hot Reloading extension then exit and try restarting the Hot Reloading.

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention, you can 'hot reload' or rebuild your app to solve this issue.

But the **reason why** I got this error, was that I have edited the `pubspec.yaml` file, when editing the `pubspec.yaml` file, you should stop and rebuild the *entire* app.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your lib folder where your main.dart file is and run the commands below:

PS C:\Users\mobile_app\lib> **flutter clean**

PS C:\Users\mobile_app\lib> **flutter pub get**

PS C:\Users\mobile_app\lib> **flutter run**

although if you are having null safety issues I would prefer you debug your application first. In my encounters this error is of a result of trying to run a class component outside a the Static Widget with context hence the class is loaded before build time making the application fail to start.

Answer (score 1):

I occurred when I was implementing `TextEditingController` and there after I created a function which has parameter inside, so when I wrote the `addListener` for the controller, then below error got occurred,

```
Unimplemented handling of missing static target flutter
```

but after removing the argument from the `addListener` function still the issue persists and which broked my application, even I did the hot reload in my `Android Studio`.

Solution:
Mostly similar to above said, but little different, I terminated my app, and rerun the app, and which fixed the issue.

Hope this would help manyone.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import.
It should be
`import 'package:your_app...'` not `import 'file://C/path/your_app/`

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023.

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
flutter run
```